# How to understand the unit of permittivity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

If permittivity is opposition against formation of electric field in a medium, why is unit of permittivity( $\epsilon$ )  ${C^2\over Nm^2}$?
I know how mathematically but how can I understand it physically? Also please try to explain like you are explaining to someone new to electrostatics.

Comment: Why you do not keep the form F.m$^{-1}$ which is meaningful compared to C$^2$.N$^{-1}$.m$^{-2}$ or A$^2$·s$^4$·kg$^{-1}$·m$^{-3}$.

Comment: In Gaussian units, permittivity is dimensionless, which is another advantage of using Gaussian units in electromagnetism.

Answer (score 1):

Every physics theory that covers a new phenomenon gets to bring in new constants and define new units, and it is very common for them to be physically meaningless.

For example, Newtonian gravity introduced the equality between inertial and gravitational mass, and Newton's constant $G$.

Thermodynamics brought Boltzmann's constant $k_B$ to us, while quantum theory brought in reduced Planck's constant $\hslash$. Einstein's General Theory of Relativity is the most special of this bunch, because it reused Newton's constant, therefore it does not actually bring in a new one. It is the exception that proves the rule.

Strictly speaking, none of $G$, $k_B$, $\hslash$ are physically meaningful. What is happening here is that the units of measurement were fixed prior to the discovery of these phenomena, and thus Nature is punishing us for using stupid units by having to keep track of all these unit conversion nonsense. If we had chosen to measure temperature in the units of energy, for example, then $k_B$ will stop appearing, because it would be just one.

Electrodynamics is a bit more special, because it brings to us quite a few of these constants at one go. The only constant that is physically meaningful is the fine structure constant, but because we did not know enough physics at the time to have foreseen this issue, we had no choice but to arbitrarily define the unit of charge, and a few other such units, and the leads to us having to define proton charge $e$, [electric constant $\varepsilon_0$](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/qy8oaHd1nlU) and magnetic constant $\mu_0$. [Note that electric constant and magnetic constant are the new standard names for them.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity#Terminology)

When Maxwell unified electromagnetism, he found out that there is no need for having both electric and magnetic constants, because together they define the speed of light in vacuum. Just before the 2019 redefinition of the SI units, the magnetic constant was defined as a specific constant, and speed of light is defined as another constant, and then the electric constant is defined in terms of them both, and is yet another constant with zero uncertainty in all three of them. Now, though, we found a better way, and the electric constant and magnetic constant each have a tiny uncertainty, but the speed of light continues to have no uncertainty, by definition.

There is thus no sense if you try to assert that physics must explain the units of a constant that is really coming due to ignorance of our pioneers.

Comment: The unit of $\hbar$ is not meaningless, but your are right for the other constants.

Comment: @M06-2x Since physicists often choose to work in units where $\hbar$ is simply the dimensionless number 1, the SI units of $\hbar$ can’t have physical significance.

Comment: So does permittivity have no actual meaning and just gives an idea about the field?